# two tier border on an anchor tag :active state

Tags: html, css

In Gmail, when I click the compose button, then move my mouse off of it without letting up on the mouse button, I get this sort of elegant two-tiered border:

[image: gmail compose button]

How is this effect being done? Can I apply this effect to an anchor tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, simply use `border-style: double`:

```
a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f00;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 6px double #fff;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f9wv9/3/).

The `border-color` here is `#fff` which appears 'within,' or between, the background-coloured segments.

If you want to get even more interesting, and have the 'outer-most border' be a different colour to the `background-color`, then you can also use `box-shadow` (or the vendor-prefixed variants) to:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f00;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #f90;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f9wv9/).

This displaces the shadow by zero units horizontally, zero units vertically, has a blur of zero units and a spread of `4px`.

The `box-shadow` approach, of course, allows for [multiple different colours](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f9wv9/2/) to be added to the outer aspect of the element. Unfortunately, though, the `box-shadow` solution doesn't displace the element the shadow is, effectively, 'intangible'. So you may have to account for the width of the shadow(s) and apply relevant margins to the `a` element elements along with `display: inline-block` (if they're to be in-line elements) to allow the margins to take effect.

Comment: No top border with this method

Comment: @Rick: yes, there is, it's simply that the border-top doesn't displace the element. This is why in the demos I used `padding-top` for the `body` element (albeit I *forgot* to include that in first linked-demo, *sigh*...edited in!)

Comment: Ahh there it is. Fair enough, less markup solution than mine too.

Answer (score 1):

Both those methods work, this is an alternative solution. Looks like it is what Gmail is using too:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9wv9/5/)

```
a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f00;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: this is also really elegant. Thanks, Adam!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/PfuJn/1/

```
a{color:white;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:block;}
.aContainer{width:80px;padding:15px;background-color:orange;border: 6px double white;}


<div class="aContainer">
<a href="#">Compose</a>
</div>​
```